# EntityReference can have no more than one related object - many to many with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

I have two lists. They are both populated through database:

- ListA: ID, PayID, PayDesc, ListB
- ListB: ID, PayID, MoneyDesc

where ListB looks like:

```
ID      PayID    MoneyDesc
1       2        a
1       3        b
1       4        c
```

The code snippet where I get an error goes something like this:

```cs
ListA.FirstOrDefault().ListB = 
    (from b in ListB where (ListA.Any(x => x.PayID == b.PayID) select b))
    .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

What I want to happen is something like:

```sql
select moneydesc 
from listb b 
inner join lista a on b.payid = a.payid
```

But I get "EntityReference can have no more than one related object" error.
However, if `ListB`'s `ID`'s are different per row, say 7, 8 and 9, respectively, the error does not occur.

How can I achieve what I had in mind? Also, shouldn't `FirstOrDefault()` be able to handle this, since it gets the first element in a sequence?

Comment: *How can I achieve what I had in mind?* -- It's not clear what you have in mind. What's the purpose of the code snippet? It seems you can just query `ListA` and `Include()` `ListB`.

Comment: I get the "EntityReference" error on the code snippet I posted. I am not familiar with LINQ but I will look into "Include()" and see if it works.

Comment: As Gert mentions, please describe what you "had in mind" and also share the code for your `ListA` and `ListB` classes. It seems to me you're using a many-to-one relation, which of course fails when rows in `ListB` have the same ID. What's wrong with using different IDs? You already mentioned that it works